# How to limit the amount of versions per file?

Tags: versioning, version-history

Our client uses Sharepoint (Office 365). They have multiple sites setup. They have a 50GB limit overall. I found that some Excel files are 3GB+ large due to it keeping 3000+ versions of the file.

We want to limit this to 100 versions only. How do I do this in Sharepoint?

Comment: Just to add, I have searched this high and low and it seems the previous answers are for differnet versions of sharepoint? I'm logged in as an admin and can see "Site Settings", but the option is not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to **List Setting** and select **Versioning settings** and limit the number of versions

[image]

Comment: this is the only correct straight forward answer

i would also add that this settings can only be applied at list/library level

Answer (score -1):

Found it by going to the "Sharepoint" in the header. Then clicking on a site, then clicking on "Edit", then selecting the file browser, then clicking on the "Library" tab at the top, then "Library Settings". The option for Versioning is there.

Looks like you have to do this with each site.

Comment: if this is your answer i'm really willing to flag you as this is a really misleading and wrong answer

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to keep versioning 'open ended' you could investigate configuring **Information management policy settings** for document libraries.

It is possible to configure a process, which is triggered automatically from a date field, you could then select an Action 'delete previous versions'

[image]

Comment: Since I've been downvoted I think I should clarify something about my answer - use Anil Pal's answer.  Look at my answer as being something additional that you may or may not wish to use in addition.